# Intentionally hiding memory via malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

So I'm working on a small memory allocation package, and I've wanted the initialization of pointers to save the size of the space allocated as well as an indicator that it was allocated via one of my functions (which is the character 'q' before the size in memory). So, I've tried to do the following:

```
int qmem_alloc(unsigned num_bytes, void ** rslt){
  *rslt = malloc(num_bytes+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char));
  *((int*)rslt) = num_bytes;
  *(char*)(rslt+sizeof(int)) = 'q';
  rslt = rslt+sizeof(int) + sizeof(char);
  if(*rslt == NULL)
    return -1;
  else if(errno != 0){
    //Catch the rest of the errors
    return -2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, it seems in my main function that the memory directly before the address of rslt does not contain what it should after being passed back. Am I doing something bad here by changing the pointer address?

Comment: looks like you messed the levels of indirection here. Such as `*((int*)rslt) = num_bytes;` should be `*((int*)*rslt) = num_bytes;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a level of indirection in a few places.  Anyplace you use `rslt` before dereferencing you should be using `*rslt`:

```
int qmem_alloc(unsigned num_bytes, void ** rslt){
  *rslt = malloc(num_bytes+sizeof(int)+sizeof(char));
  if(*rslt == NULL)
    return -1;

  *((int*)*rslt) = num_bytes;
  *(char*)(*rslt+sizeof(int)) = 'q';
  *rslt = *rslt+sizeof(int) + sizeof(char);
  if(errno != 0){
    //Catch the rest of the errors
    return -2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also, the memory returned by `malloc` is properly aligned for any use.  Because you return `sizeof(int)+sizeof(char)` == 5 bytes past that (assuming a 4 byte `int`) which means the pointer you return is probably not.  You'll want to add at least 3 more bytes to put the returned buffer on an 8 byte boundary.

Comment: Thank you! But I am still having problems in main...
"printf("Size of pointer: %d", (int*)(p-sizeof(int)))" is still producing a segmentation fault

Comment: You didn't look back far enough.  There's a `char` between the size and the start of the buffer.

Comment: Ah, it took me 15 minutes to parse this incredibly simple and correct solution, but you were right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Within your function *rslt* is the address of the pointer.  You should not be modifying or even accessing that.  If you're trying to change/read the address where the pointer is pointing to, than you need to use **rslt*.  If you're trying the modify/read the value of what the pointer is pointing to, you need to use ***rslt*.

@dbush describes the result of the above in code.